# Left Join on closest or equal date-time stored as int

Tags: time, hive, match, rank

I am comparing data between the old system and the new system and need to join 2 tables with HIVE by an exact datetime match (stored as int) or the nearest datetime (stored as int). I have seen similar problems solved with RANK() but just don't get it.

table1  (eqmt_id, event_code, event_dt)

```
bnsf13589, PA, 202104211300 
bnsf13589, PA, 202104211600 
bnsf13589, PA, 202104212000
```

table2  (eqmt_id, event_code, event_dt)

```
bnsf13589, PA, 202104211400 
bnsf13589, PA, 202104211600 
bnsf13589, PA, 202104212100
```

Desired Result

```
bnsf13589, PA, 202104211300, 202104211400
bnsf13589, PA, 202104211600, 202104211600
bnsf13589, PA, 202104211200, 202104212100
```